# Javadoc link to class in default package?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Small preface: This is an assignment for my university that the grader has specified to **NOT** use package statements. I am personally working on improving my commenting skills so my code could potentially be used by others for group projects and the like.

Is there a way that I could use the link tag to link to another class/method within the default package?

Example:

```java
/**
*
* @return A call to {@link ClassInDefaultPackage.methodA}
*
*/
```

Again, I cannot declare packages, so the default package **MUST** be used.

Best Regards!

**EDIT:** I believe it likely this cannot be achieved. A simple confirmation of impossibility would be very much a desirable answer.

Comment: Is the class where this javadoc appears also in the default package?

Comment: Yes. All classes are in the default package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes in the default package cannot be imported by classes in packages. This is why you should not use the default package.

But if all your classes are inside default package `@link` should work --> 

`/**
*
* @return A call to {@link ClassInDefaultPackage#methodA}
*
*/`

Comment: Thank you. That works just fine. It appears using the pound sign was where I was having my issue when referring to the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference between classes in the default package. The issue here doesn't seem to be the package, but the fact that you should `#` instead of `.` to deliminate between the class and its method:

```java
/**
 *
 * @return A call to {@link ClassInDefaultPackage#methodA}
 * Here -----------------------------------------^
 *
 */
```